# How to prove the following application of the Stiltjes series expansion

Tags: complex-analysis, measure-theory, power-series, pade-approximation

We begin with a density given by
$$
\tag 1
K(\xi)=\sum_{k=1}^K p_k\delta\left(\xi -\xi_k\right) 
$$

The question is how to prove the following
$$
\tag 2
\int_0^{max(\xi)}K(\xi)\frac{(z\xi)^{1-K}}{1-z\xi}d\xi=\sum_{k=1-K}^{K}z^kM_k
$$

where the moment equation 
$$
\tag 3
\sum_{k=1}^Kp_k(\xi_k)^m=M_m,
$$
holds. 
I don't understand how the summation limits in (2) are derived and why the term $(z\xi)^{1-K}$ is needed. I also don't understand how this relates to the formula 
[for the Stiltjes transformation given here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation)

Motivation:
The reasoning behind this is to find the values of $\xi_k$. This is done using the theorem, which states that if we would define 
$$
f(z)=\int_0^\infty\frac{d\phi(u)}{1-zu}
$$
for a real, non-decreasing and bounded function $\phi(x)$ for $x\in[0,\infty)$, for $\forall z \in \mathbb{C}\setminus \left ( \mathbb{R}^+ \right ) $ exists the series expansion in terms of the moments $f_j$
$$
f(z)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^\infty f_j z^j
$$

By using the $[N+1][N]$ Pade expansion it can be shown that
$$
f(z)=\frac{a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\dots +a_{N+1}z^{N+1}}{b_0+b_1z+b_2z^2+\dots +a_{N}z^{N}}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\frac{w_i}{z-z_i}.
$$

In that case the poles $z_j$ are simple and real. The proof of the above statement can be found [in this paper](https://ac.els-cdn.com/0021904575900775/1-s2.0-0021904575900775-main.pdf?_tid=89b062e5-578e-4ba2-acfb-356b98178ff5&acdnat=1521317233_d8a1f02c3e9e75d6d51c3a211b83644e). (pdf link)

Comment: This could make sense if it was $p_k \delta(\xi - \xi_k) $ in (1). Also, I guess the upper limit in (3) should be $K$.

Comment: I am sorry, I had some typos. I corrected the limit and inserted the delta function. However, the computation in (2) is still a mystery.

Comment: I would formally (worrying about rigorous justification later) expand the denominator in (2) as a series and evaluate the integral using (1).

Comment: I meant expanding $1/(1-z\xi)$. I tried it, but I get $\infty$ instead of $K$ for the upper limit on the RHS of (2). I don't recall seeing a moment $M_k$ defined for negative $k$.

Comment: In $f(z)=\int_0^\infty\frac{d\phi(u)}{1-zu}$ if we take $w=1/z$ and $g(w)=\frac{1}{w}f(\frac{1}{w})$ then $g(w)= \int_0^\infty\frac{d\phi(u)}{w-u}$.

Answer (score 0):

(2) can't be correct because the LHS has poles at $z=(\xi _k)^{−1},k=1,...,K$.